# Javascript - Reflecting encapsulated members

Tags: javascript, oop, class

I created a javascript "class" as follows:

```
function MyClass(member1, member2) {
   this.Member1 = member1;
   this.Member2 = member2;
}
```

All members are Strings.

I want to take an instance of MyClass and "clean" the members by calling

```
function NoneBecomesNull(item) {
    if (item === "[None]")
        item = "";
    return item;
}
```

for-each member of the class.  Is there an effecient way to accomplish this task?  (In the case where MyClass has 30 members).

I would like to avoid doing...

```
myClassInstance.Member1 = NoneBecomesNull(myClassInstance.Member1);
myClassInstance.Member2 = NoneBecomesNull(myClassInstance.Member2);
//...30+ times
```

Comment: JavaScript isn't a Class based object-oriented-language, it's prototype-based. Stop trying to shove a square hole over a round peg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
for (var name in theObject) {
  if (theObject.hasOwnProperty(name) && theObject[name] === "[None]") {
    theObject[name] = "";
  }
}
```

I used `hasOwnProperty` to prevent the reseting of properties higher up in the prototype chain.  Your example didn't show the use of a prototype chain here and hence it's likely not necessary for this example.  But it's good practice.

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't want to encapsulate this behaviour... seems like it would dirty up your app code.

Comment: @jondavidjohn - both solutions work well.    I picked JaredPar because he answered the question with a work-able solution first.I gave you +1 for the improvement.

Comment: yeah, for sure, just was pretty happy with my answer and wouldn't want you to move on and not see it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not encapsulate this behaviour inside your object?

[***WORKING EXAMPLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/82QwL/1/)

```
function MyClass(member1, member2) {
    this.Member1 = member1;
    this.Member2 = member2;
    this.clean = function() {
        for ( var member in this ) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(member) && this[member] === "[None]") {
                this[member] = "";
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Then it only takes one line to accomplish...

```
var obj = new MyClass("[None]", "hello");

obj.clean();
```

Comment: I believe the OP only wants to reset members with the value `"[None]"`.  Here you are resetting every member

Comment: no, becuause the checking is done inside the function he provided `NoneBecomesNull` which i changed to `Empty` to be more accurate

Comment: This wouldn't completely work because the function sets the argument, not the original member.

Comment: [None] becomes null from the db perspective.  The conversion happens in the BL.